# Update title of button in for loop in swift UIButton

Tags: swift, xcode, uiview, uibutton, custom-keyboard

I have been trying to change the title of my UIButton every iteration of a for loop in swift, but it doesn't work as the titles are not being updated.
Heres the code:

```
@IBOutlet var generateButton: UIButton!
var x: Double = 0.0
for i in 0...nTokens {
    x = (Double(i)/Double(nTokens)) * 100
    print(self.generateButton.isHighlighted)
    self.generateButton.setTitle("\(x) %", for: .highlighted)
    self.generateButton.titleLabel!.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20)
    sleep(3)
}
```

Have already linked generateButton to the correct button in the view, and self.generateButton.isHighlighted always print true. What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not Sure how your sleep function looks like.Could you make sure that

```
self.generateButton.setTitle("\(x) %", for: .highlighted)
```

runs in main thread ?

Answer (score 0):

```swift
self.generateButton.setTitle("\(x) %", for: .normal)
```